# Circular dependencies C++

Tags: c++, circular-dependency

I'm trying to compile something like the following:

A.h

```
#include "B.h"
class A {
    B * b;
    void oneMethod();
    void otherMethod();
};
```

A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
void A::oneMethod() { b->otherMethod() }
void A::otherMethod() {}
```

B.h

```
#include "A.h"
class B {
    A * a;
    void oneMethod();
    void otherMethod();
};
```

B.cpp

```
#include "B.h"       
void B::oneMethod() { a->otherMethod() }
void B::otherMethod() {}
```

Until now I haven't had problems using forward declarations, but I can use that now, because i can't use atributtes or methods of only-forward-declarated classes.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You've just asked a whole 'nother question. For *this* question, you'll get a crash in the compiler due to the circular `#include` logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as I'm understanding your question right, all you need to do is this:

A.h

```
class B;// Forward declaration, the header only needs to know that B exists
class A {
    B * b;
    void oneMethod();
    void otherMethod();
};
```

A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"//Include in the .cpp since it is only compiled once, thus avoiding circular dependency
void A::oneMethod() { b->otherMethod() }
void A::otherMethod() {}
```

B.h

```
class A;// Forward declaration, the header only needs to know that A exists
class B {
    A * a;
    void oneMethod();
    void otherMethod();
};
```

B.cpp

```
#include "B.h" 
#include "A.h"//Include in the .cpp since it is only compiled once, thus avoiding circular dependency      
void B::oneMethod() { a->otherMethod() }
void B::otherMethod() {}
```

Answer (score 6):

In C++, unlike Java and C#, you can define a member function (providing its body) outside the class.

```
class A;
class B;

class A {
    B * b;
    void oneMethod();
    void otherMethod() {}
};

class B {
    A * a;
    void oneMethod();
    void otherMethod() {}
};

inline void A::oneMethod() { b->otherMethod(); }
inline void B::oneMethod() { a->otherMethod(); }
```

Comment: No need to add `{}` for `othermethod()` inside class na ?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: I don't understand what you're asking.  "class na"?

Comment: Sorry, I have my code splited into .cpp and .h files. I have edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @Trollkemada: Actually, you've edited the question to make it a *completely different question*. Which makes all the existing answers invalid.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill  sorry about that, should I close this and open other question?

Comment: Yeah looking at the edit this is a pretty significantly different question after the edit

Answer (score 1):

You must defer using the members of a class until after that class is defined. In your case, that means moving some member function bodies to the bottom of the file:

```
class B;

class A {
    B * b;
    void oneMethod();
    void otherMethod() {}
};

class B {
    A * a;
    void oneMethod() { a->otherMethod() }
    void otherMethod() {}
};

inline void A::oneMethod() { b->otherMethod() }
```

---

Here is a typical solution in multiple files:

A.h

```
class B;
class A {
    B * b;
    void oneMethod();
    void otherMethod();
};
```

B.h

```
class A;
class B {
    A * a;
    void oneMethod();
    void otherMethod();
};
```

A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

void A::oneMethod() { b->otherMethod() }
void A::otherMethod() {}
```

B.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

void B::oneMethod() { a->otherMethod() }
void B::otherMethod() {}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
int main () { A a; a.oneMethod(); }
```

Comment: If I'm using .cpp and .h files (the code is splitted) do I need to implement some functions in the .h file? (I don't like that :\)

Comment: You don't have to if you don't want to. If you implement them in the .h, they must be marked `inline`. If you implement them in the .c, do not mark them `inline`.

Comment: If I implement them in the .cpp i get a compile error becaouse b is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Push the implementation of your functions into cpp files and then the cpp can include both headers.